# how to have two fadin, delay and fadeout afther another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to i do when i click a button it will first `.fadeIn(0); .dealy(2000); .fadeOut(600); and say "Validating..."` THEN it will say `"Success fully log in"` and redirect to index.php?

i did try this but it did not work:

```
function save() {
    $('#save_first').html('Validating...');
    $('#save_first').fadeIn(1);
    $('#save_first').delay(2000);
    $('#save_first').fadeOut(600);
    $('#save_second').html('Success fully log in!');
    $('#save_second').delay(2601);
}
```

HTML

```
header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
```

Comment: Any way you could share a bit of html so I can make a quick fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack them up and use a callback for the rest along with a setTimeOut for the redirection

```
var loginUser = function(){

    $('#save_first').fadeIn(1).delay(2000).fadeOut(600, function(){
        $('#save_second').html('Success fully log in!');
        //Redirect after 2.6 seconds delay
        setTimeout(function() {
           window.location.href = "/index.php";
        }, 2600);
    });

};
```

then whenever you want this to trigger just do :

```
loginUser();
```

to trigger on click of "element" do :

```
$(element).click(loginUser);
```

Comment: oki but how do i redirect them to a side after the is done? @charlitosJS

Comment: Just use the setTimeout function to redirect. I updated the code with it.

Comment: It should work as long as "#save_first" exists in your page, also make sure your code is inside a document ready call back just like in my last edit. You also have to wait 5.6 seconds for the redirect to occur.

Comment: missing function save(){…} I guess that's the function @user2733334 is calling on click.

Comment: okay it readirect but its not showing "Success fully log in!"

Comment: it should as long as '#save_second' exists in the page and as not hidden. If hidden, you have to fade that one in as well.